# How do sparse word embeddings fail to capture synonymy?

Tags: natural-language-processing, word-embedding, sparse-word-embedding

While reading some explanations of why dense word embeddings work better than sparse word embeddings, the following statement has been given in the chapter [Vector Semantics and Embeddings](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/6.pdf), showing a drawback of sparse word embeddings.

> Dense vectors may also do a better job of capturing synonymy. For example, in a sparse vector representation, **dimensions for synonyms like car and automobile dimension are distinct and unrelated**; sparse vectors may thus fail to capture the similarity between a word with car as a neighbor and a word with automobile as a neighbor.

It says that the dimensions of synonyms may be unrelated and distinct. I am facing difficulty in understanding it.

Can anyone provide me a simple example to understand it by taking some simple dimensions which are unrelated and distinct?

You can consider either documents or (context) words as dimensions for the example.